# Passing a value from one blade but not necessarily from other blades

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to let the user click on a notification and it will become read (highlighted), and at the same time will open a blade (e.g. thread/post).
I need to pass the ID of the clicked notification along with the post_id from the blade to the showPost method in the postController. I will then make an update statement in the method to change the "read" boolean field to 1. 
As per my understanding, If I add the ID of the notification to the route, I will have to pass this value if I open the post from any other blade as well. I feel laravel has a way to tell the method to only process/expect the notification Id if it's coming from notifications.blade.php, while if the user opened the post from his main page for example, then no need to pass the notification_id, as well as no need to do the update in the notifs table. Any suggestions ?

notifications blade sample :

```
@if($notification->data_type==1) 
 <a href="/StuffSpot/posts/{{ $notification->data_id }}"> <strong>{{$notification->send_uname}}</strong> has commented on <strong>{{$notification->title}}</strong> post</a>
```

route :

```
Route::get('/posts/{post}', [ 
    'uses' => 'PostController@showPost',
    'as' => 'showPost',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

method:

```
public function showPost($id)
    {

        $posts=Post::find($id);
        $comments = Comment::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
         return view('showPost', ['post' => $posts] , ['comments' => $comments]);
    }
```

Update to be added in the method :

```
DB::table('notifs')->where('id', $notif_id)->update(['read' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a separate action to set the notification read and then simply redirect to showPost action with the original posts id. I persume the post is related to the notification.